# Swift getter syntax during declaration

Tags: swift

In Grand Central Dispatch, the QOS classes are available under Swift like this:

```
public struct qos_class_t : RawRepresentable, Equatable {
    public init(_ rawValue: UInt32)
    public init(rawValue: UInt32)
    public var rawValue: UInt32
}

@available(iOS 8.0, *)
public var QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE: qos_class_t { get }

@available(iOS 8.0, *)
public var QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED: qos_class_t { get }
```

What does `{ get }` means and how are the values of these QOS variables set in the first place? Unlike Obj-C there is no header/source separation, so I kind of got confused. If it's just an int, why is a structure declared in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `{ get }` properties are usually computed properties. You don't trust them with storing any real values. But, when asked for them, they do some computation and return a value based on state.

Example :

```
struct Integer {
    var value : Int
    var square : Int {
          get {
              return value * value
          }
    }
}
```

Its header file would look something like :

```
struct Integer {
    var value : Int
    var square : Int { get }
 }
```

By this, it is plain that they are not *set*, they are *computed*.

As for your second question, I have no idea. I would have created a `typealias` in these kind of situations; something like :

```
typealias qos_class_t = UInt32
```

But I really cannot criticise this design decision without more context.

Comment: When we write Swift, we don't actually write the header file. So what is it really? A "view" of the prototypes of the closed source?

Comment: @huggie "Headers" are auto-generated in Swift for you. If you go into assistant editor, and go Counterparts > FileName.swift (Interface), you'll see the auto-generated "header".

Comment: That's the same header I am referring to.